# Render Coloured Point Clouds as Collection of Spheres

Tags: rendering, color, point-clouds

I have a coloured point cloud in a `.pcd` file, that I can easily convert to a `.ply` file using [Open3D](http://www.open3d.org/). I would like to visualise the point cloud in Blender (version 3.x) as a collection of spheres, each coloured according to the colour of the corresponding point in the point cloud, in order to render a high-quality image.

The final result should look something like the following, where the colours are the ones specified in the `.pcd` file:

[image]

Is there a simple way to achieve this with Blender?

---

Image source:

> F. Sverrisson, J. Feydy, B. E. Correia and M. M. Bronstein, "Fast
> end-to-end learning on protein surfaces," 2021 IEEE/CVF Conference on
> Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition (CVPR), 2021, pp. 15267-15276,
> doi: 10.1109/CVPR46437.2021.01502.

Comment: It's a bit involved but you might find interesting things in this thread over on BA https://blenderartists.org/t/render-large-point-cloud-with-color-information/1375273

Comment: Thank, I'll have a look but I never used Blender before, therefore I was looking for a simple solution. Looks like the Point Cloud Visualizer plugin would do what I need, but the price is a bit steep since I need it for just a few renders.

Comment: There is a builtin .ply importer that you can use. I don't know if it will import the color data though